# Extraction Date in business objects

Tags: datetime, business-objects

I am using Business Objects Edge and on a report I want to create has a front cover and I was hoping to add the month and year of the previous month in the following format:

September 2015

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
B

Answer (score 0):

I dont have access to BO Edge, I mocked up the following in BOE WebI XI3.1:

```
=FormatDate(RelativeDate(CurrentDate();(DaysBetween(CurrentDate(); ToDate("01/" + FormatDate(CurrentDate();"MM/yyyy"); "dd/MM/yyyy"))-1)); "Mmmm yyyy")
```

This gives you the days between now and the start of the month, which today will give you -26 and because we want last month then you would minus another day.  Then using I formatted the date so that it appears as the Month Year.